# Javascript Three.js point camera at fixed coordinate

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Javascript THREE.js, given the coordinates of the camera and the coordinates of a point (`x`, `y`, `z`), how would I rotate the camera to look directly at the point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the camera "look at" a world-space point by using the `lookAt()` method, like so:

```
var point = new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z );

camera.lookAt( point );
```

---

Note: This method is limited, in that it will not work correctly if the camera is a child of another rotated or translated parent object. However, if the camera has no parent, or if the camera is a child of the scene directly, then the method will work as expected.

three.js r.71

Comment: Wow. I'm quite frankly surprised that my googling didn't find that function!